# Override ShiroWebModule filter and realm

Tags: guice, shiro

I am using Apache Shiro to secure my jesey-guice application.  I have defined a SecurityModule by extending ShiroWebModule as described in the [example](http://shiro.apache.org/guice.html).

For non-production environment, I have different security requirements, so I have defined DevSecurityModle  with a different (and less restrictive) set of filters.  I was hoping to do something in the line of:

```
Modules.override (new SecurityModule()).with (new DevSecurityModule());
```

However, I realized that Modules.override only override bindings, and since both bindRealm() or addFilterChain() are not bindings, I am simply adding new security realm and filters.

How how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My impression is that `DevSecurityModule` is meant as a drop-in replacement of `SecurityModule`. If that's the case, then why not just install `DevSecurityModule` instead of `SecurityModule` in your development binary, and vice versa for production?